# update sharepoint list by getting data from xml file

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Guys I need your help.

I have a list and it contains two columns: Title and Scale

```
List                                         xml
-----                                        ---------
Title      Scale                             root

Title1     1                                    <Scale>1</Scale>
title2     3                                    <Scale>3</Scale>
title3     5                                    <Scale>5</Scale>
title4     8                                    <Scale>8</Scale>

and so on
```

The title field is already filled in, let say with the values: Title1, title2 and Title3.
Now, I would like to fill the Scale field with values from a xml file.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. Can you help please???

Answer (score 0):

As for what I know, you cannot enter it through the xml file.
But I am pretty sure you can use a c sharp code to edit each item (SPListItem)